# create string in Matlab using only some parameters

Tags: regex, string, matlab

In Matlab, is it possible to create a string like:

```
f1-*f2-*f3-*f4-*f5-*f6
```

giving only as parameters:

`f`, `1:6` and `-*` ?

I tried:

```
for i=1:6; str = strcat(str, sprintf('f%d %s',i,'-* ')); end
```

but it doesn't work very well and seems ineficient for a larger number of files... Perhaps a `regexp` would be more suitable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) for using `-*` as a delimiter, and [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) for combining the numbers with `f`:

```
>> strjoin(strcat('f',sprintfc('%d',1:6)),'-*')
ans =
f1-*f2-*f3-*f4-*f5-*f6
```

Because `strcat` accepts cell arrays, no loop is needed.

Answer (score 3):

This gives you the string with extra trailing separator:

```
str = sprintf('f%d-*', 1:6)
```

Perhaps you can just remove the last two characters from this. In general, a single `sprintf` for an array input is quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
% //Data:
letter = 'f';
numbers = 1:6;
separator = '-*';

%// Let's go:
num = mat2cell(num2str(numbers(:)), ones(1,numel(numbers))); %// cell array
%// of strings from the numbers. Those strings may contain spaces.
%// Those will be removed later
s = strcat('f',num,'-*'); %// concatenate letter and separator to each number
s = [s{:}]; %// contatenate all
s = s(1:end-numel(separator)); %// remove last separator
s(s==' ') = []; %// remove spaces (in case of several-digit numbers)
```